# Integrating New Relic with Tornado app with gunicorn as a process manager

Tags: python-2.7, tornado, gunicorn

I want to use New Relic to monitor errors in my Async Tornado app with gunicorn as a process manager.

When I try to make a request after integrating with New Relic I get the following error 
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.10.1.9/newrelic/hooks/framework_tornado.py", line 30, in request_environment
result['REQUEST_URI'] = request.uri
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'uri'

The app is hosted on Heroku
requirements.txt

```
# Analytics
newrelic==2.10.1.9
```

Procfile

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn -k tornado --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT opening_application.runserver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround to eliminate the issue is to add the following to the agent configuration file (newrelic.ini):

```
[import-hook:gunicorn.app.base] 
enabled = false
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, Joel. Are there any downsides to this workaround? And do you know if New Relic has a bug on file to fix this?

Comment: I did not have any downside for this workaround. I guess New Relic is aware about the issue and is planing on having a fix for it in the next release.